# Google charts csv ignore first rows

Tags: csv, charts

I have the below google charts code which reads from a local CSV file on my web server.

This is great & works well.

However, the files I will be using when this goes 'live' will be auto-generated and have a header of 10 rows, which I want to ignore (data should not be read).

Is there any way to alter this script to ignore the first 10 lines of the CSV file?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   // load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartfromCSV);

   function drawChartfromCSV(){
     // grab the CSV
         $.get("EDU_INST_SCHOOL_EXPENDTR_29_1.csv", function(csvString) {
         // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
            var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
         // this new DataTable object holds all the data
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
         // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,2]);
         var options = {
         title: "EDUCATIONAL INSTITUTIONS, SCHOOLS AND EXPENDITURE - INDIA",
          hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
          vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(2), minValue: data.getColumnRange(2).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(2).max},
          legend: 'none'
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('csv2chart'));
          chart.draw(view, options);
         });
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the elements from the array before creating the DataTable...

[Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first element from an array

```
     // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
        var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

     // remove unwanted headers
        var removeRows = 10;
        while (removeRows--) {
          arrayData.shift();
        }

     // this new DataTable object holds all the data
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
```